# How do i order wordpress posts by a meta value in a specific order?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type in WordPress, the post type is called 'Real estate'. It holds Real estate objects, all of which have a meta key of 'status' with one of these values:
'Sold', 'Sold subject to change', 'Available'.

How do i write a WP_Query that orders these objects based on a specific order of statusses. For example, i want the objects with the 'Available' status first, then 'Sold subject to change' and lastly 'Sold'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters, you can set

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
'meta_key' => 'status'
```

It's going to order alphabetically by default, so with statuses 'Available',  'Sold subject to change' and 'Sold', it should work. As far as I'm aware, you cannot use custom sorting with WP_Query.

Or you can execute WP_Query 3 times, once for each status and show the results any way you want.